# How to fix XFCE's xflock4 reapeatedly launching the screensaver?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, lock-screen, 23.04

I just upgraded to Xubuntu 23.04 and it turns out that now, `xflock4` repeatedly launches the screensaver when locking the screen, even if I keep moving the mouse and typing into the keyboard, it keeps turning the screen into black and showing the screensaver **again and again for something around 14~30 times**. Then it finally prompts me for password.
Any idea on how can I fix this?

EDIT 1: Found out that the `xflock4` script is using `xfce4-screensaver-command --lock` which triggers this behavior.

EDIT 2: Found some information on system log
[System log with xfce4-screensaver errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggY7p.png)

The error says

`2023-09-19T23:29:12.006960-03:00 NuttyUbuntuPC kernel: [ 7073.989930] traps: xfce4-screensav[31206] general protection fault ip:55a1bbce7ef1 sp:7fff9edf54e0 error:0 in xfce4-screensaver-dialog[55a1bbcdd000+e000]`

EDIT 3: Filed a bug at [xfce4-screensaver-command --lock keeps failing to show dialog and launches screensaver repeatedly](https://gitlab.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-screensaver/-/issues/136)

Answer (score 0):

The bug was already solved in version `4.18.0` [GitLab Tag xfce4-screensaver-4.18.0](https://gitlab.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-screensaver/-/tags/xfce4-screensaver-4.18.0)

A developer explained why it's still happening, thought. [Developer's Comment](https://gitlab.xfce.org/apps/xfce4-screensaver/-/issues/125#note_70720)

It seems the only solution for now is to wait for Xubuntu's next release

... or to use the [Xubuntu QA Staging PPA](https://wiki.xubuntu.org/devel/ppa)

**But remember the disclaimer: "As these packages (and new package versions) are primarily geared towards testing, they can be removed from the PPA at any time by the Xubuntu developers. Please DO NOT consider this PPA a main, stable source for the packages."**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/experimental
sudo apt update
```

There you'll find `xfce4-screensaver 4.18.2-1~bpo23.04`